# Does the "The definitive guide to form-based website authentication" still have any value?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Most likely no. If [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/549/792066) was asked today, it would have been closed as too broad. The answers are not novel and there are already better guides on the internet, since they are more focused either in the generic concepts (like securing the connection, storing secrets, 2FA, etc.) to actual implementation (search "form login" and "language/framework"). Any user that stumbles upon this question is already doing more research than the average user (and has to use the word "definitive" otherwise it will not appear on the first page of search results) so we can expect them to not need this.

Someone already archived the [top answer](https://gist.github.com/sweded/4047691), and the specifics are already several guides that cover the same topic elsewhere. Do still have value or can we be done with it? Locking is not appropriate since it seems to be maintained (it was recently edited, to add some jokes for some reason) and it would prevent those edits.

Comment: The icing in the cake is that it is using the article tag to mean that it's meant to be a blog post article, not because it pertains to articles.

Comment: *"Locking is not appropriated since it seems to be maintained (it was recently edited, to add some jokes for some reason) and it would prevent those edits."* -  Locking would prevent joke edits? Sounds perfectly appropriate.

Comment: @Nick no, jokes edits are prevented by suspensions, and proper rollbacks. Deletion would achieve the same as locking but without user education.

Comment: Do people still use form-based website authentication? If so, I would say the answer is obvious.

Comment: *"Deletion would achieve the same as locking but without user education."* So you clearly think we should lock it, right? Because user education is good.

Answer (score 15):

Yes, it still has value.

The information presented in that "article" is more or less still up-to-date. It might not be suitable for our format, but as long as it doesn't harm new developers, and even better still helps them, it should remain visible.

The post helped me when I was learning about authentication systems few years ago and I still think it will help many people in the future. **Do not delete it!**

Comment: What do you say about locking?

Comment: It has a historical lock at the moment. That is the correct choice for content that is not appropriate for Stack Overflow but still has value.

Comment: @Braiam historic lock sounds very good here.

Comment: "but as long as it doesn't harm new developers, and even better still helps them" I mean, they can't even find it anyways, what help is doing them? BTW, how did you find it?

Comment: @VLAZ Care to elaborate why?

Comment: ["can't even find it"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUPz2.png). Also #1 on Google and #2 on DuckDuckGo

Comment: @Braiam the information *is* useful. Even if it's old it's relevant. So, keeping the information is appropriate. The question isn't appropriate for SO's standards, though. That's why we have the historic lock for - old content that is not going to be accepted today but is nonetheless useful. Also, we don't need any new answers to this.

Answer (score 8):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The only part of this I agree with is:

> Locking is not appropriate since it seems to be maintained

While locking prevents deletion of a useful resource, it also prevents maintenance, which has been going on for years—the main answer is on revision 54.  I'd consider some other moderator notice not to delete the question, but we should allow it to be edited.

Comment: For that reason, I would be willing to keep it unlocked. This was maintained by a number of people and locking it completely now means that it will become stale after some time.